# How do I get the current compute capability of a GPU from the host portion of the code?

Tags: cuda, visual-studio-2017, compile-time, nvcc, preprocessor-directive

I tried to use `__CUDA_ARCH__` but I read somewhere that this works only on the device portion of code.
After that, I came across this code on github: [link](https://github.com/divijverma/NAMD/blob/dce41777d099e647965a8dc5e3fec1925027110f/src/DeviceCUDAkernel.cu)

Is there any better way to achieve this?

I am asking this because I would like to determine (on host code) if the GPU supports unified memory in which case a cudaMallocManaged would take place or cudaMallocs && cudaMemcpys would take place instead.

Example of what I would like to do:

```
int main() {
  // IF CUDA >= 6.0 && COMPUTE CAPABILITY >= 3.0
      // USE cudaMallocManaged
  // ELSE
      // USE cudaMallocs && cudaMemcpys
  // END IF
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think there is a code example in the SDK for getting the compute capability.

Comment: @PaulR so you suggest that i should use `__host__ ​cudaError_t cudaGetDeviceProperties ( cudaDeviceProp* prop, int  device )` and read the value from the `managedMemSupported` variable. What if I would like to compile the exact same code with some older CUDA API that doesn't even have the definition of what is `cudaMallocManaged`?

Comment: I don't know - it's a long time since I did any work with CUDA - I just remembered that there was a code sample in the SDK which reported compute capability, that's all.

Comment: @PaulR Oh ok! Thanks anyway! ;)

Comment: Note there is a difference between querying the compute capability via `cudaGetDeviceProperties()` and `__CUDA_ARCH__`: The former gives the actual compute capability of the device, while the latter gives the compute capability the device code has been compiled for. They can differ where different compute capability devices are binary compatible or if PTX code gets translated for the actual architecture by the driver.

Comment: @tera Yes that's true.

Comment: @tera I would like to make compilation possible on newer and older CUDA 
 at compile time (i want compilation without errors) AND detection of whether unified memory is supported at run time.

Comment: In that case you'd be best off [querying unified memory support directly](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__UNIFIED.html#group__CUDART__UNIFIED) rather than inferring it from the compute capability.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/xorz57/b074171188b17baa1d4050522ca5d59f Here is what I did with all the help you gave me guys. Let me know if you don't like something.

Comment: The include file `cuda_runtime_api.h` has a `#define CUDART_VERSION xxxx` which can be used to test the runtime API version at compile time. After including that file, you can do something like `#if CUDART_VERSION  >= 6000` to test if the supported runtime API version is 6.0 or higher.   Even if it is, you should still use the `cudaGetDeviceProperties` method described above to verify support for managed memory, before attempting to call e.g. `cudaMallocManaged()`.

Comment: @RobertCrovella This seems to be a great solution. Can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seem to be two questions involved here:

1. How can I query (at compile time) the CUDA runtime API version that a particular code is being compiled for, so that I can determine whether it is safe to use certain runtime API elements (such as those associated with managed memory) which may only have appeared in newer runtime API versions?

   One method is already discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37970880/how-to-get-cuda-toolkit-version-at-compile-time-without-nvcc/37971432#37971432).  As a condensed version for this particular case, you could do something like:

   ```
   #include <cuda_runtime_api.h>
   ...
   // test for CUDA version of 6.0 or higher
   #if CUDART_VERSION >= 6000 
   // safe to use e.g. cudaMallocManaged() here
   #else
   // e.g. do not use managed memory API here
   #endif
   ```
2. How can I determine if I can use managed memory at run-time?

   As already mentioned in the comments, if you have established that the CUDA version being compiled against is CUDA 6.0 or higher (e.g. see above) then you should test for support for managed memory before attempting to use `cudaMallocManaged` for example.  The `deviceQuery` [CUDA sample code](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#device-query) indicates a general methodology (for example using [`cudaGetDeviceProperties`](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__DEVICE.html#group__CUDART__DEVICE_1g1bf9d625a931d657e08db2b4391170f0), testing the `managedMemSupported` property) for testing capabilities, at run-time.